# Html inline text is not following relative/absolute positioned radio/checkbox

Tags: html, radio-button, absolute, inline-code

`Inline text` of `radio/checkbox` is not following it if they are relatively/absolutely positioned. I want to do it with inline text only. How can I make it work?

```
<input type="radio" style="position:absolute; left:30px;top:40px;">Hi Follow me</input>
```

I tested it in Chrome 25.

Comment: Dirty way would probably be to put the control inside a div and use your styling on a div. Just a guess though.

Comment: can we say this is a browser issue, & its going to be solved in future?

Answer (score 1):

It's very common to wrap the `<input />` in a `<span />` or `<div />`:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:30px;top:40px;">
    <input type="radio" name="blah" />Hi Follow me
</div>
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/HUS5n/)